# JQuery addClass to first visible child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with several un-ordered lists that are just like the code below with the exception of the #7 and the uppercase letters, which are dynamically built from db data.  Based on a user action on the page, all or some of the list elements will show or not.  What I need to do is add the class "with-headers" to the first visible list element that is a child or under a ul with a class="minimal-product".  The "with-headers" class is added automatically through other css or javascript included in the file when the page loads.  I am trying to override it with my JQuery.

```
<div id="course-group-7" class="content active">
  <ul class="minimal-products zebra-stripes">
    <li class="fos-crs-HPA minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container with-headers" style="display: none;">
    <li class="fos-crs-HLD minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container even" style="display: list-item;">
    <li class="fos-crs-HRM minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container" style="display: list-item;">
    <li class="fos-crs-SPH minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container" style="display: none;">
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried a few things but cannot get this to work.  Seems like this should work.  Using firebug, I found I do not need to remove the "with-headers" class first, but thought it would be better code to do so.

```
$('ul.minimal-products li').removeClass("with-headers");
$('ul.minimal-products li:visible:first').addClass("with-headers");
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `$('ul.minimal-products li:visible:first').addClass("with-headers");` works for me

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you running this code before the DOM is ready?

Comment: page is fully loaded.  Then user selects option in drop-down list.  That triggers my jquery.  Must be the code in the main css and/or javascript is preventing my efforts.  will dig into that next.  Thanks for looking though!

Comment: Are there multiple uls with `minimal-product` class in the page? Could you do a `$("ul.minimal-products").length` and check?